# getting system Null reference error

Tags: null

I've been at this for a while and can't seem to figure out why I'm getting the error "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object" for the  "comments.add(com)" line below

```
    public list<Approval_Request__c> comments;
    public List<Approval_Request__c> getcomments(){

            for(Approval_Request__c com : [SELECT Id,
                                                  Approver_Comments__c
                                                  FROM Approval_Request__c
                                                  WHERE parentId__c IN (SELECT Id
                                                                        FROM HigherParent__c   
                                                                        WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppId)
                                                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                                                           ]){
                                                           if(com.Approver_Comments__c.contains('Approved with comments')){
                                                               ***comments.add(com)***;}
                                                           }
            if(comments.size() > 0)
            return comments;
            return null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is probably coming in

`if(com.Approver_Comments__c.contains('Approved with comments')){`.

One of the records returned by the SOQL query might have a null value in Approver_Comments__c field and there is a contains check on that. You would have to put a null check on this field before applying contains.

Something like this:

```
    if(!String.isEmpty(com.Approver_Comments__c) && com.Approver_Comments__c.contains('Approved with comments'))
    { 
       comments.add(com);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized this `list<Approval_Request__c> comments` but you are trying to check the size using `comments.size()` and adding items into the list.

This will work:

```
public list<Approval_Request__c> comments = new List<Approval_Request__c>();
    public List<Approval_Request__c> getcomments(){

            for(Approval_Request__c com : [SELECT Id,
                                                            Approver_Comments__c
                                                            FROM Approval_Request__c
                                                            WHERE parentId__c IN (SELECT Id
                                                                                  FROM HigherParent__c   
                                                                                  WHERE Opportunity__c = :oppId)
                                                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC 
                                                           ]){
                                                           if(com.Approver_Comments__c.contains('Approved with comments')){
                                                               **comments.add(com)**;}
                                                           }
            if(comments.size() > 0)
            return comments;
            return null;
```

Comment: Thanks Ashwani, I have tried this as well and still get the error.